# App crashes if question is reloaded without data connection

Tags: bug, android-app, page-load

100% reproducible.

Reloading a feed or a search result without a connection gives a proper error message. Questions and answers just crash.

This happens both when you use the pull down to refresh feature, and when you rotate the app.

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.0.82 (beta)<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been fixed:

- Reloading the Q&A thread without a connection doesn't make the app crash, and now gives a proper error message "*Loading the question failed.*" with <kbd>Cancel</kbd> and <kbd>Retry</kbd> options.

  Note: dismissing the dialog (by pressing <kbd>Cancel</kbd> or <kbd>Back</kbd> buttons) will return to previous screen (e.g. question list, feed, etc), while pressing <kbd>Retry</kbd> will try  to reload the thread. (There's no way to dismiss the dialog only and return to the thread without internet connection at the moment)

  [image: loading the question failed.]
- Rotating the app also doesn't make it crash. It will display the thread without trying to reload it (no error dialog).